# Best way to download .png,.pdf,.mp3,.mov in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am working on app where user can purchase downloadable product which can be anything pdf mp3 png etc. How can we download those product so that user can access them outside the app.

Thanks

Comment: This question is too broad. You have to be more specific on SO. If you are designing this app and you have a particular problem with the code people will probably help you out. Check: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

As you mention in your question that you have to access out side the application, In that case you have to create app extensions

Comment: But my main concern is where i have to save those. if i store in document directory and if downloadable product is some kind of software than how user can access it or copy it for using